# How to update table view when a row is updated/deleted/inserted without reloading the entire component

Tags: angular, datatable

I want to update/delete/insert a row and update table view once submit button is clicked. Currently, my `component.ts` reloads the component after submit button is clicked. Also, I only have update functionality for now. I'll add the delete and update as soon as this issue is fixed.

Example `component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { MyApi } from './../my-api';
import { MyApiService } from './../my-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-table',
  templateUrl: './my-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-table.component.css'],
  providers: [MyApiService]
})
export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit {

    myApi: MyApi[];
    dataId: number;
    dataState: string;

    options = [
        { state: "MSG_ERROR" },
        { state: "MSG_WAIT_FA" },
        { state: "MSG_WAIT_BATCH" },
        { state: "MSG_COMPLETE" }
    ]

    constructor(
            private myApiService: MyApiService,
            private location: Location,
            private router: Router
        ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.myApiService.getMyTables()
        .subscribe(myApi => this.myApi = myApi);
    }

    save(data): void {

        this.dataId = data.id;
        this.dataState = data.state;

        this.myApiService.updateMyTableState(this.dataId, this.dataState)
        .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
    }

    goBack(): void {

        this.router.navigateByUrl('', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
        this.router.navigate(["/home/my-api/my-table"]));
    }

}
```

This is my `component.html`:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-menu></app-menu>
<app-settings></app-settings>
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                      <h3 class="box-title">MSG WAIT FA</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <table *ngIf="myApi" datatable class="table table-borderless table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Doctype</th>
                                    <th>Sender</th>
                                    <th>Receiver</th>
                                    <th>Count</th>
                                    <th>Created</th>
                                    <th>Resolution</th>
                                    <th>State</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let data of myApi">
                                    <td>{{ data.doctype_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ data.sender_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ data.receiver_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ data.count }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ data.created }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ data.resolution }}</td>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <select [(ngModel)]="data.state">
                                            <option *ngFor="let o of options" [value]="o.state">{{ o.state }}</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" [disabled]="data.state == 'MSG_WAIT_FA'" (click)="save(data)"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- / table -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- / box body -->
                </div>
                <!-- / box -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

This is my `service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { MyApi } from './my-api';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class MyApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private myApiUrl = 'http://path/to/my-api';

  getMyTable (): Observable<MyApi[]> {

    return this.http.get<MyApi[]>(this.myApiUrl + '/msg_wait_fa');
  }

  updateMyTableState(dataId: number, dataState: string): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.put(this.myApiUrl + '/msg_wait_fa/update/' + dataId + '/' + dataState, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

The issue with my code is when I search for a specific string in my DataTable search box and update a row, the component will reload back from it's original view not showing rows defined by the string in the search box. Imagine if there are many rows with the same string you supplied in the search box. Each time I update one row, the component will reload again and I type the string in the search box again to update another row. I have tried subscribing to `ngOnInit()`  function when a row is updated and it updated the table view without refreshing the entire component. The problem is, it shows all the records and not the indicated string in the search box.

What I want is when I update a row, the table view will update too but show only the records corresponding the string on the search box.

**UPDATE:** I want my table view be similar to this but still using JQuery DataTable or Angular DataTable

https://github.com/marinantonio/angular-mat-table-crud

Comment: Since myApi holds your data, updating the myApi object should also update the view. Your code shown has the pieces for saving, but doesn't appear to show any search box, or search mechanism. If you are having issue with the table re-rendering all the data rather than just what you've searched for, then the issue is probably localised to just that. Maybe it's just as simple as a flag to indicate searching is underway, and then rather than looping through myApi as the displayable data, have a similar variable to show that accounts for searching etc.

Comment: What about using `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after `this.myApi = myApi` in the call on the onInit?

Comment: @rrd, I'm using JQuery DataTable that's why it has search box.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, I'm still learning Angular. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @WashichawbachaW add this in the constructor: `constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cdr: ChangeDetectionRef) { }` then in the `onInit` -> `this.myApiService.getMyTables()
        .subscribe(myApi => this.myApi = myApi; this.cdr.detectChanges(););`

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi, I got an error TS1005: ')' expected. I just followed your code, `ngOnInit() { this.myApiService.getMyTable().subscribe(myApi => this.myApi = myApi; this.cdr.detectChanges(); );
   }`

Comment: @WashichawbachaW whups, my bad. Here's the update written better: `this.myApiService.getMyTable()
    .subscribe(myApi => {
      this.myApi = myApi; 
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, thanks it refreshes the table rows, but it shows all rows not the rows matching the string written in the search box.

Comment: What do you do when you delete a row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184063/discussion-between-washichawbachaw-and-jacopo-sciampi).